# 20% Off one item in a category not working

Tags: cart, price, rules, shopping

I'm trying to give 20% off one item in a particular category but the rule I set up is giving 20% off more every item from that category added to the shopping cart.  I have the rule set up to limit discount to one item but it's not working.  Any suggestions?

Comment: show the rule...

Comment: why don't you just apply the discount on the product if it's for 1 product?

Comment: Please update your question with a screenshot of conditions and actions tab

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother writing a rule here. Just go to Catalog > Manage Products > YourProductName > Prices and set the `Special Price` you want.